# Microsoft Access sql query to find records where all values in a column match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a similar to below:

| ProductID | Division | OrdNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 011 | 123 |
| 1 | 705 | 123 |
| 1 | 660 | 123 |
| 2 | 011 | 511 |
| 2 | 705 | 412 |
| 2 | 660 | 216 |

I am trying to write a query that will return each product ID and if the OrdNum for all Divisions is the same it will return the OrdNum, and if the OrdNums are different it will return "Varies"

The results should look like this:

| ProductID | OrdNum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | Varies |

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the min and max values:

```sql
Select 
    ProductID,
    IIf(Min(OrdNum) = Max(OrdNum), First(OrdNum), "Varies") As OrderNumber
From
    YourTable
Group By
    ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query may work for you.

```
select t2.ProductID,iif(t2.OrdCount>1,"Varies",DLookup("[OrdNum]","[Table1]","[ProductID]="&t2.ProductID)) as OrdNum
from (select t1.ProductID, count(t1.ProductID) as OrdCount
from (select ProductID, OrdNum, Count(Division) AS CountOfDivision from Table1 group by ProductID, OrdNum) as t1 group by t1.ProductID) as t2
```

[image]